# SpringData - Sorting by joining table, without duplicates in first table

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have `PersonEntity` which is in `oneToMany`relation with `AddressEntity`.

Also, I have `Specification<PersonEntity>` and `Pageable` objects already defined.
My pageable object has sorting by `addresses.city`.

Without sorting I have proper results, but if sorting is by city I have duplicates in my return page. If I add to my specification `query.distinct(true)` it fails in runtime, because `sort by` is not in select results.

Basically I need to join only first result in second table (addresses) or somehow remove duplicates. How it can be done?

**EDIT:**

```
personRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
// specification contains only (root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(root.get(PersonEntity_.orgId), orgId)
// pageable - sort asc, addresses.city, page 0, pagesize 100
```

Of course problem is that after I sort by addresses.city, when Person has more than one address it will do LEFT OUTER JOIN which produces me two results.

**EDIT2:**

There is a open issue in github https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1150
Do we have any workaround with jparepositories?

Comment: Can you please post your actual code, the result and the desired result?

Comment: @JensSchauder edited

Comment: Sorting a person by address.city just doesn't make sense, since every person has several cities.

Comment: I thought, that it takes first from list

Comment: Actually it sorts by city, I just want to clear duplicated Persons from list. It can be first from each

Comment: There is a open issue https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1150 Do we have any workaround with jparepositories?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
})
```

As the name *HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH* says, it does not pass the distinct keyword to SQL and hibernate will take care about filtering distincts.

e.g.

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
})
@Query("select distinct p from Product p left join fetch p.reviews re order by re.text desc")
List<Product> findAll();
```

produces the following SQL

```
select
    product0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    reviews1_.id as id1_2_1_,
    product0_.name as name2_1_0_,
    reviews1_.product_id as product_3_2_1_,
    reviews1_.text as text2_2_1_,
    reviews1_.product_id as product_3_2_0__,
    reviews1_.id as id1_2_0__ 
from
    product product0_ 
left outer join
    review reviews1_ 
        on product0_.id=reviews1_.product_id 
order by
    reviews1_.text desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across similar issue, to avoid duplicate records in your resultset use @Where with clause.

Use something like

```
@OneToMany
@Where(clause="<column name of Address that will give you distinct result>")
List<Address> addresses;
```

At runtime, where clause is appended to query after left outer join.

Hope it helps to resolve your query!..